# How to find duplicates in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I want to compare 2 arrays by values and not keys. For example:

```
$array1 = array(0 => 'wow', 1 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar');
$array2 = array(0 => 'foo', 1 => 'wow', 2 => 'bar');
```

are not unique.

Is there any function for this?

Thanx!

Comment: Could you elaborate on "compare"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) - Compares array1 against array2 and returns the difference.

[array_diff_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) - Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

```
array_intersect(
    array('wow','foo','bar','baz'),
    array('foo','wow','bar','fiz'),
)
// Output
// [ 'wow', 'foo', 'bar' ]
```